# Getting Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setVolume' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, text-to-speech

I have investigated the cause of this error and looks that it can be due to not initializing flutterTts. I am initializing it in several points of the code and I see that it gets executed as the control string "Initializing TTS" is printed. Even so, I keep getting the above error.
Could you give a hand with this issue?

The widget where the speak method that throws the error is called is included here:

```
import 'package:facebook_audience_network/facebook_audience_network.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:insurance_dictionary/tts_helper.dart';
import 'facebook_code.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Destination extends StatefulWidget {
  final String entry;
  final String definition;

  Destination({this.entry, this.definition});

  @override
  DestinationState createState() => DestinationState();
}

class DestinationState extends State<Destination> {
  bool isInterstitialAdLoaded = false;
  FlutterTts flutterTts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    FacebookAudienceNetwork.init(
      testingId: "37b1da9d-b48c-4103-a393-2e095e734bd6", //optional
    );
    loadInterstitialAd(); //This was called in main
    loadBannerAd();
    super.initState();
    TtsHelperState().initTts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          widget.entry,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Center(
        //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.definition,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 60,
              child: RaisedButton(
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  TtsHelperState().initTts();
                  TtsHelperState().speak('Hola, Radiola');

                  // Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                color: Colors.blue[900],
                child: Text(
                  "Say it!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 60,
              child: RaisedButton(
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                color: Colors.blue[900],
                child: Text(
                  "Back to Contents",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //bannerAd
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bannerAd,
    );
  }
}
```

The tts_helper.dart file is included here:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

class TtsHelper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TtsHelperState createState() => TtsHelperState();
}

enum TtsState { playing, stopped }

class TtsHelperState extends State<TtsHelper> {
  FlutterTts flutterTts;
  dynamic languages;
  String language;
  double volume = 1.0;
  double pitch = 1.0;
  double rate = 0.5;

  String _newVoiceText;

  TtsState ttsState = TtsState.stopped;

  get isPlaying => ttsState == TtsState.playing;

  get isStopped => ttsState == TtsState.stopped;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initTts();
  }

  initTts() {
    print('Initializing TTS');
    flutterTts = FlutterTts();

    getLanguages();

    flutterTts.setStartHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        print("playing");
        ttsState = TtsState.playing;
      });
    });

    flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() {
      setState(() {
        print("Complete");
        ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });

    flutterTts.setErrorHandler((msg) {
      setState(() {
        print("error: $msg");
        ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
      });
    });
  }

  Future getLanguages() async {
    languages = await flutterTts.getLanguages;
    print("pritty print ${languages}");
    //  if (languages != null) setState(() => languages);
  }

  Future speak(String text) async {
    print('Volumen: ' + volume.toString());
    await flutterTts.setVolume(volume);
    await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(rate);
    await flutterTts.setPitch(pitch);

    if (text != null) {
      if (text.isNotEmpty) {
        print('POR AQUI PASA');
        flutterTts.setLanguage('en-US');
        var result = await flutterTts.speak(text);
        if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.playing);
      }
    }
  }

  Future stop() async {
    var result = await flutterTts.stop();
    if (result == 1) setState(() => ttsState = TtsState.stopped);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    flutterTts.stop();
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getLanguageDropDownMenuItems() {
    var items = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();
    for (String type in languages) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: type, child: Text(type)));
    }
    return items;
  }

  void changedLanguageDropDownItem(String selectedType) {
    setState(() {
      language = selectedType;
      flutterTts.setLanguage(language);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

The full listing of the error that I am getting is this:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro Max...
Reloaded 7 of 860 libraries in 305ms.
flutter: Initializing TTS
flutter: Volumen: 1.0
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setVolume' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setVolume(1.0)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      TtsHelperState.speak (package:insurance_dictionary/tts_helper.dart:71:22)
#2      DestinationState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:insurance_dictionary/destination.dart:67:36)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
#4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:259:7)
#9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (pack<…>
flutter: pritty print [ja-JP, cs-CZ, fr-FR, hi-IN, sv-SE, es-ES, fi-FI, en-ZA, da-DK, fr-CA, ko-KR, nl-NL, no-NO, zh-CN, ru-RU, en-IN, pt-BR, ro-RO, he-IL, sk-SK, zh-TW, en-AU, el-GR, id-ID, tr-TR, pt-PT, en-GB, hu-HU, de-DE, ar-SA, en-IE, it-IT, nl-BE, pl-PL, en-US, zh-HK, es-MX, th-TH]
[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it working. Thanks @BabC for your comments that leaded me to the correct direction.

The fact that TtsHelper was defined as a widget was inherited by the example that is published in the flutter_tts documentation package.
I have reworked it to be a collection of methods just like another helper .dart files that I have in my project and now it works.

This is the resulting tts_helper.dart file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

enum TtsState { playing, stopped }

FlutterTts flutterTts;
dynamic languages;
String language;
double volume = 1.0;
double pitch = 1.0;
double rate = 0.5;

String _newVoiceText;

TtsState ttsState = TtsState.stopped;

get isPlaying => ttsState == TtsState.playing;
get isStopped => ttsState == TtsState.stopped;

initTts() {
  print('Initializing TTS');
  flutterTts = FlutterTts();

  getLanguages();

  flutterTts.setStartHandler;
  {
    print("playing");
    ttsState = TtsState.playing;
  }
  ;

  flutterTts.setCompletionHandler;
  {
    print("Complete");
    ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
  }
  ;

  flutterTts.setErrorHandler((msg) {
    print("error: $msg");
    ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
  });
}

Future getLanguages() async {
  languages = await flutterTts.getLanguages;
  print("pritty print ${languages}");
  //  if (languages != null) setState(() => languages);
}

Future speak(String text) async {
  print('Volumen: ' + volume.toString());
  await flutterTts.setVolume(volume);
  await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(rate);
  await flutterTts.setPitch(pitch);

  if (text != null) {
    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      print('POR AQUI PASA');
      flutterTts.setLanguage('en-US');
      var result = await flutterTts.speak(text);
      if (result == 1) ttsState = TtsState.playing;
    }
  }
}

Future stop() async {
  var result = await flutterTts.stop();
  if (result == 1) ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
}

@override
void dispose() {
  // super.dispose();
  flutterTts.stop();
}

List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getLanguageDropDownMenuItems() {
  var items = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();
  for (String type in languages) {
    items.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: type, child: Text(type)));
  }
  return items;
}

void changedLanguageDropDownItem(String selectedType) {
  language = selectedType;
  flutterTts.setLanguage('en-US');
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build
  throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

I have tested it with the iOS simulator and it works perfectly.
Thanks, again @BabC

Answer (score 0):

You declare TtsHelper as a Widget, or you use it as a service. So you should create a simple class TtsHelper.

When you use `TtsHelperState().initTts();`, you instantiate an object and initialize it. But when you do this : `TtsHelperState().speak('Hola, Radiola');` you instanciate a new object, which is not initialized with your method `initTts()`.

So you should rework you code TtsHelper to use it as a service :

```
class DestinationState extends State<Destination> {
  bool isInterstitialAdLoaded = false;
  FlutterTts flutterTts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FacebookAudienceNetwork.init(
      testingId: "37b1da9d-b48c-4103-a393-2e095e734bd6", //optional
    );
    loadInterstitialAd(); //This was called in main
    loadBannerAd();

    flutterTts = new TtsHelperService();
    flutterTts.initTts();
    // Then use flutterTts.speak(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried it and  it doesn't work. If I put flutterTts = new TtsHelperService(); just like you mention, I get two compliation errors: 1.- The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'FlutterTts' , 2.-  The name 'TtsHelperServce isn't a class

I can solve compiling errors by changing to flutterTts = new TtsHelperState() as FlutterTts; which solves the type issue and the non-existing class issue, but in execution time I get this new error: Capture from onError type 'TtsHelperState' is not a subtype of type 'FlutterTts' in type cast